# Probability of winning prizes

Tags: probability

Special Drawing where you pay \$10 to play.
There were 500 tickets sold a possible 5 prizes won. 
The first place prize gets \$500. 
Four second place prizes award \$100 each. 
What is a prob. distribution table for the problem and expected value for the \$10 ticket?

I understand that .002 (1-(499/500)) is the probability of winning the first prize and that .008 (1-498/499)) is the probability of winning the group of 4 remaining tickets. However I do not know how to put this in a table that accounts for all 5 prizes and get the sum of 1.

Comment: expected value for the what?

Answer (score 1):

```
Prize  Prob  Prize*Prob

$500   0.002     $1 

$100   0.008     $8

$0     0.99      $0

Sum    1         $9
```

So the expected value would be $\$9$, or $-\$1$ net of the price of the $\$10$ ticket

Comment: I suggest you check the arithmetic.  $.002 \cdot 500=1$, not $10$.  One rarely sells tickets with positive expectation.

Answer (score 0):

the probability of not getting anything is $\frac{495}{500}$, while the probability of $\$100$ is $\frac{4}{500}$ and the probability of $\$500$ is $\frac{1}{500}$.  If you add up all of the probabilities, you get $1$, as you should.